# returning one result from a pyopencl kernel

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

My pyopencl kernel program is started with global size of (512,512), I assume it will run 512x512=262,144 times. I want to find the minimum value of a function in my 512x512 image but I don't want to return 262,144 floats to my CPU to calculate the min. I want to run another kernel (possibly waiting in the queue ) to find the min value of all 262,144 pixels then just send that one float to the CPU. I think this would be faster. Should my waiting kernel's global size be (1,1), ? I hope the large 262,144 Buffer of floats that I created using mf.COPY_HOST_PTR will not cross the GPU/CPU bus before I call the next kernel.

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 2):

Andreas is right: reduction is the solution. Here is a nice [article](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/) from AMD explaining how to implement simple reduction. It discusses different approaches and the gain in terms of performance they bring. The example in the article is about summing all the elements and not to find the minimum, but it's fairly trivial to modify the given codes.

BTW, maybe I don't understand well you first sentence, but a kernel launched with a global size of (512, 512) will not run 262,144 times but only one time with 262,144 threads scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

Use a reduction kernel to find the minimum.